# Change my static data with the dynamic data from an API

Tags: reactjs, filtering

I have created a ReactJS application which can display the data from an API and has a category list which can filter the data of items based on category.

Now what I want is to change my categories list which are static so that it is updated dynamically with the API so that even there is more number of categories I don't need to write them all down manually.

so this is my static category list for filtering data which is written manually:

```
<ul>
  <li className={toggleState === 1 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>{toggleTab(1); setData(mainArray)}}>All</li>
  <li className={toggleState === 2 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(2, "Pizza")}>Pizza</li>
  <li className={toggleState === 3 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(3, "Bread")}>Bread</li>
  <li className={toggleState === 4 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(4, "Shakes")}>Shakes</li>
  <li className={toggleState === 5 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(5, "Ice-Cream")}>Ice Cream</li>
  <li className={toggleState === 6 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(6, "Cakes")}>Cakes</li>
  <li className={toggleState === 7 ? "tabs active" : "tabs"} onClick={()=>toggleTab(7, "Juices")}>Juices</li>
                </ul>
```

I want to get the categories list dynamically from my API :

https://63b6952d1907f863aafa9342.mockapi.io/menu/

the data in API is in this way:

```
[
  {
   "Name": "Chicken pizza",
   "Category": "Pizza",
   "Type": "non-veg",
   "Price": 376,
   "id": "1"
  },
{
   "Name": "Brown bread",
   "Category": "Bread",
   "Type": "veg",
   "Price": 45,
   "id": "2"
  },
{
   "Name": "vanilla ice cream",
   "Category": "Ice-Cream",
   "Type": "veg",
   "Price": 25,
   "id": "3"
  }
 ]
```

I have created the categories list which can filter data manually so it is static and I need to change the categories by myself.

So I want a way by which the categories are to be displayed from API having the filter functionality.

I'll provide the sandbox link if you need anymore understanding with the code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qr-menu-smvr6h?file=/src/App.js

Guide me the way which can help me to solve the issue I faced.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your data dynamically like this

```
<ul>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <li
            key={item.id}
            className={toggleState === item.id ? "tabs active" : "tabs"}
            onClick={() => {
              toggleTab(item.id, item.Category);
              // setData(mainArray);
            }}
          >
            {item.Category}
          </li>
        ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: It helped me a lot and one more thing is that I'm getting duplicate values of same category. How can I remove them and also I want set another item in category to display all items.

Comment: In my API I have the multiple items with same categories.

Comment: you can filter your API response by adding logic when you set your data. There are many ways, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-duplicate-elements-from-javascript-array/, if the above answer helped you then accept this answer